# Does going from Windows Server 2008 R2 Release Candidate to RTM require full re-install?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

I was going to download and deploy Server 2008 R2 in on a hyper-v server but found this on windows server blog.

If you are a Volume License (VL) customer with an existing Software Assurance (SA) license, you will be able to download Windows Server 2008 R2 RTM on August 19th via the Volume License Service Center (VLSC).

I want to install standard 2008 R2 core version which runs asp.net for our VM webserver. Should I just expect that I will have to install another VM with the RTM release and move the website over to that image after the fact. I want to get something up and runnning on our new server this weekend.

Comment: Get a deployment and role-based provisioning of your servers going - so you easily can wipe and reload any server in your sleep. Upgrades can go wrong and it's a good idea for disaster recovery anyway to be intimately skilled in wipe and reload ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just looking into this today. The Win7 and 2008R2 installer media contains a text file with minimum-versions allowed to upgrade. On Win7 its something like build 7400 (RC was 7100), so on the client, RC-to-RTM isn't supported. Windows 2008 R2, however, supports upgrades from around build 6900 if I remember the number correctly - which suggests that late beta and RC upgrades to RTM are supported.

Please take the numbers with a grain of salt, as this is just from the top of my bumpy head.

Google "Windows 7 RC to RTM upgrade" to find details around this

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's been a late-breaking change, upgrades from RC to RTM are supported.

From a Beta to RTM is not supported, and requires a reinstall.

Comment: So going from RC to RTM i slike applying a service pack then?

Comment: Note that you usually *can* make it work, it's just not a good idea.

Comment: @Breadtruck: Essentially, yes, but its via the full setup process. From what I've seen with previous RC builds 99% of the system will be the same, just updated build numbers, finalized text strings, etc. Occasionally there are security bug fixes that were important enough for the RTM too.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded 2 servers through 2k8 SP1 => SP2 => R2 RC => R2 RTM

The VM's have only been powered down during the host OS upgrades

All the VM's had the HyperV Integration Components upgraded after the host OS was upgraded.

I have had no problems at all on any of these servers and the VM's they host.

Comment: Thanks, I also had no problems upgrading my two servers either. Microsoft actually got the whole process right!